# Why does creating a very large vector of zero sized items take forever while an array is fine?

Tags: rust

This code runs fine:

```rust
use std::mem::size_of;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", size_of::<[(); usize::max_value()]>());
    let x = [(); usize::max_value()];
    println!("done");
}
```

It immediately prints `0` and `done`. The array is 0 bytes large after all, so this is expected.

If I use a `Vec` however, things look different:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = vec![(); usize::max_value()];
    println!("done");
}
```

This runs a very long time and never prints `done`. **Why is that?** I also expect the vector to have 0 actual size. So it shouldn't need to allocate or write any memory. What is taking so long?

This only happens when I compile without optimizations. With optimizations, it finished immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your array expression `[(); usize::max_value()]` is understood and interpreted directly by the compiler. The `vec![(); usize::max_value()]` expression on the other hand is a macro. So let's see what it expands to!

Using `cargo expand`, I get:

```rust
let x = ::alloc::vec::from_elem((), usize::max_value());
```

You won't find this methods in the docs as it's `doc(hidden)`. You can see it [in the source here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1e179690f8ad9790eb3a6b1dbb6a0ddf479f2c86/src/liballoc/vec.rs#L1727-L1731). It delegates to a trait to specialize for certain types for performance. In the `()` case, [this impl](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1e179690f8ad9790eb3a6b1dbb6a0ddf479f2c86/src/liballoc/vec.rs#L1738-L1744) is used. This mainly calls the private method `extend_with`, [defined here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1e179690f8ad9790eb3a6b1dbb6a0ddf479f2c86/src/liballoc/vec.rs#L1620-L1646).

And there we finally see the problem: a `for _ in 1..n` loop. Without optimizations, this loop isn't removed and thus, the program takes forever trying to perform `usize::max_value()` loop iterations.